# Double Progress Bars with update via AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I am developing an app that downloads files and show 2 progress bars, the first one for the current downloading file, and the 2nd one for total progress based on the number of files.

I am using the [DoubleProgressBar](https://github.com/simao/Android-DoubleProgressBar) library in my app:

I succeeded to update the first ProgressBar, but stuck with the 2nd one.

Here is my code for the AsyncTask class:

```
private DoubleProgressDialog pDialog;

    class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        Context mContext;

        public DownloadFileFromURL(Context ctx) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.mContext = ctx;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(CUSTOM_PROGRESS_DIALOG);
        }

        /* Downloading file in background thread */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {

            InputStream input = null;
            OutputStream output = null;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                // getting file length
                int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
                for (int i = 0; i <= ArrayOfFiles.length; i++){
                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Folder/", ArrayOfFiles[i]);

                // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
                input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
                // Output stream to write file
                output = new FileOutputStream(f); 

                byte data[] = new byte[8192];

                long total = 0;
                int count;
                int EntireProgress = 0;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    // allow canceling with back button
                    if (isCancelled()) {
                        input.close();
                        return null;
                    }
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    if (fileLength > 0) // only if total length is known
                    publishProgress((int)(total * 100 / fileLength));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);

                        /*Here is my trouble, the 2nd ProgressBar is updating as the same of the first one, I need the 2nd one to update itself slowly till all files get downloaded*/
                    int CurrentProgress = pDialog.getProgress();
                    pDialog.setSecondaryProgress(CurrentProgress );
                    publishProgress(CurrentProgress );

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                return e.toString();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (output != null)
                        output.close();
                    if (input != null)
                        input.close();
            }
                } catch (IOException ignored) {
                }

                if (connection != null)
                    connection.disconnect();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
            dismissDialog(CUSTOM_PROGRESS_DIALOG);

            if (result != null)
                Toast.makeText(mContext,"Download error: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(mContext,"File downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
            // if we get here, length is known, now set indeterminate to false
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setMax(100);
            pDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }

    }
```

I also used this method in my activity class:

```
    @Override
        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            switch (id) {
            case CUSTOM_PROGRESS_DIALOG:
                pDialog = new DoubleProgressDialog(NetworkActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
                pDialog.setMax(100);
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.setButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.cancel();
                    }
                });
                pDialog.show();
                return pDialog;
            default:
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Any idea?

Comment: `publishProgress(CurrentProgress );` what does this method do? ALSO : you are treating only one file but want to update the second progress based on multiple files?

Comment: Try to move `pDialog.setSecondaryProgress(CurrentProgress );` to `onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress)`. Since you're updating the UI from a non-UI thread that could be the problem

Comment: @cosmincalistru , This method can be invoked from doInBackground(Params...) to publish updates on the UI thread while the background computation is still running. Each call to this method will trigger the execution of onProgressUpdate(Progress...) on the UI thread. onProgressUpdate(Progress...) will note be called if the task has been canceled.

Will update my code to download multiple files.

Comment: @super-qua , it works but the 2nd ProgressBar resets itself once the first file downloaded, then it normally counts again with the 2nd file, then resets when it finishes, any idea, i.e. how to save current progress for the first file and add up when 2nd file is downloading?

Comment: you are declaring the 'DownloadFileFromUrl` class in your main `Activity`? or is it a separate class?

Comment: @cosmincalistru , yes, its in my main activity.

Comment: than check my answer. it should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part is to move `pDialog.setSecondaryProgress` to the `onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress)` method.
You are also resetting the secondary progress in each download task by setting it to `CurrentProgress` which is set to `pDialog.getProgress();`. Hence the second progress will always be  reset after the download is finished.

Edit:

```
// publishing the progress....
if (fileLength > 0) // only if total length is known
    publishProgress((int)(total * 100 / fileLength), pDialog.getSecondaryProgress());

(...)

int CurrentProgress = pDialog.getProgress();

// do not update secondary progress here
// pDialog.setSecondaryProgress(CurrentProgress );
int secondaryProgress = (CurrentProgress + 100 * i)/ArrayOfFiles.length;
publishProgress(CurrentProgress, secondaryProgress);
```

And the onProgressUpdate

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
   super.onProgressUpdate(progress);

   (...)       

   pDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
   pDialog.setSecondaryProgress(progress[1]);

}
```

Comment: I tried this, but the 2nd ProgressBar filled quickly and stuck at 100%, :(

Comment: What maximum do you set for the second ProgressBar?

Comment: If I got your point, I think via xml? if yes then, I set no max for both my ProgressBars, if not, then in my code, there is only 1 ProgressBar with primary and secondary progress so, I setMAx for my pDialog only

Comment: Ah ok, I thought you were able to set a maximum. In this case you have to divide the progress for the 2nd ProgressBar by the number of files. I updated my answer

Comment: still getting the same, I did that but now it delays for sometime then filled up quickly :(

Comment: Yeah you're right. Do you need to update your secondProgress continuously, or would it be enough if it updates once a file is done loading?

Comment: I would be glad if you show me how to do it updating continuously :D

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer once more. This only works if you know the `fileLength`. Otherwise you could always update the secondProgress once the first progress is 100 with `getSecondaryProgress + (100/number_of_files)`

Comment: the 2nd prog. bar still resetting itself once a file downloaded, now, I spent 5 days and the problem still not solved, what to do?

Comment: I updated my answer again. (Borrowed the nicer secondaryProgress calculation from @cosmincalistru). Make sure you're not resetting your `secondaryProgress` anywhere

Answer (score 1):

If you are not setting your `DownloadFileFromUrl` outside your main class I would suggest something like this

```
int CurrentProgress = pDialog.getProgress();
int secondaryProgress = (CurrentProgress + 100 * id_treated_file)/number_of_files;
// id_treated_file - 0, 1, 2, ... , number_of_files - 1
pDialog.setSecondaryProgress(CurrentProgress);
// secondaryProgress will be progress[1] in your onProgressUpdate method
publishProgress(CurrentProgress, secondaryProgress);
```

your `onProgressUpdate` method should look like this :

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
    // if we get here, length is known, now set indeterminate to false
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setMax(100);
    pDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
    pDialog.setSecondaryProgress(progress[1]);
}
```

**EDIT**
or you can try

```
 pDialog.setSecondaryProgress((progress[0] + 100 * id_treated_file)/number_of_files);
```

Comment: the line: pDialog.setSecondaryProgress(progress[1]); gives me ArrayIndexOutOfBound as there is only the 0 index value, however, if I modified it as this: pDialog.setSecondaryProgress(progress[0]/NumOfFiles); , it works but it resets itself every file download task

Comment: this should work if you use the current file number for `id_treated_file` and the number of files treated in total for `number_of_files`